# Rewrite url post_tag for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, url-rewriting, tags

I have used post_tag for Custom post type. I want to create a new URL structure of post_tag for each custom post types.

Example:
domain.com/tag/tag_name/

domain.com/post_type_1/tag/tag_name/

domain.com/post_type_2/tag/tag_name/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
```

in your custom post type and tag would appear as you wished for

Comment: Hi, You don't understand my question. I want create new URL rewrite for post_tag for each custom post type:

domain.com/post_type_1/tag/tag_name/

domain.com/post_type_2/tag/tag_name/